# (Done) Reopen: How can I gauge market demand for my skills before going freelance?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I asked this question yesterday, which appears to have been voted closed as 'too broad':

[How can I gauge market demand for my skills before going freelance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119572/how-can-i-gauge-market-demand-for-my-skills-before-going-freelance?noredirect=1#comment374482_119572)

Was this question closed appropriately? I don't agree that the question is 'too broad' - it seems to me to be scoped appropriately, in a way that is comparable with most other questions that are asked on the site.

If it is too broad, how should I change it to make it more appropriate?

If it isn't too broad, is it possible that it could be re-opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some small edits and voted to reopen as well. I removed a statement about your specific background to make it less about you and more about the process of determining your value. I also added a question to hopefully more explicitly call out what you are trying to determine. Feel free to edit the question further if you don't think I fully addressed what you're looking for.

Comment: I think the edits improved the question, good shot

Comment: Ok, thank you. The edits look good :-)

Comment: It's reopened now.

Comment: Thanks! @MonicaCellio

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The post is now open again.

---

> Was this question closed appropriately?

**I don't agree that the question should be closed.** It already has an answer so it is *clearly* answerable.

The question in the title is definitely ok and answerable. The second question on the body *perhaps* could be a bit broad, but not something extreme (IMHO that is)

I casted a vote to Reopen, currently 2 votes are casted...

Comment: I don't think having an answer is relevant for a question being eligible for closing due to <category> - especially if the category is *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: @StianYttervik when people vote as too broad, and there is an answer, it is then clearly not so broad after all, and perhaps just something the voter didn't grasp completely.